# Azure AD OAuth Authentication with ADAL: what's the resource ID?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, oauth, office365, adal

I'm trying to access the SharePoint [Online] REST API from an external application. I've registered it in Azure under an admin account and assigned it the appropriate user-delegated permissions (`Office 365 SharePoint Online`).

I use ADAL.js to make a call to `acquireToken` and use that token in my `Authorization` header. A valid-looking token is getting attached, but I'm getting the following 401 error in the response:

`Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown`

The acquireToken() method does take a `resource` param, and from what I've read online, this value for the SharePoint API should be `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com`, but that only returns a `null` bearer token.

What I do instead (which triggers the previous 401 error) is to simply set the resource to the app ID generated in Azure. That ends up getting set as a token in my localStorage cache. So that bearer token does return, but I get the exception.

Two questions:

1. What is the resource string, and what is the proper value to call on acquireToken(), seeing that calling it with my app ID (same thing I'm using as the client ID in my ADAL config) is the only value which returns a bearer token successfully? Is there a list of proper resource strings for each Microsoft API? I've been having trouble finding documentation on this topic.
2. Is the problem with my configuration on Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. i see an additional response header was returned (x-ms-diagnostics: 3000003;reason="Invalid audience Uri 'f8f8d2ad-7c9d-4aac-80eb-3f00a263c879'.";category="invalid_client")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the SharePoint online REST, we can use the discovery service REST to find the SharePoint service endpoint. You can find all the service resource id from the **serviceResourceId** of response.

You can also consider using the [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) which exposes multiple APIs from Office 365 and other Microsoft cloud services through a single endpoint.

More detail about discovery service REST API, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations).